# How to serialize dataRow to xml and get bytes array?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

How to serialize single DataRow to xml and then to byte array?
What is the best way to serialize data row to xml?
Should I create class, set value from dataRow to class object and then serialize to bytes? Is it better way?

Comment: It all depends on your purpose... serialized data are typically intended to be deserialized at some point with some technique and the information that's needed on deserialization is what determines the right serialization.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [DataSet.DataTable.DataRow (Single) to XML String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9135294)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

            dt.WriteXml(stream);

            stream.Position = 0;

            byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);


        }
```